# ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, sql-scripts, azure-runbook

While running the SQL script via Powershell Runbook on Azure. I am getting an error :

> ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)

Comment: Could you please provide your sql script and describe your issue in detail?

Comment: Are you able to execute same query with SQL Server Management studio in same system? A similar error message will display if your port is blocked.